# pySpark Create DataFrame from RDD with Key/Value

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

If I have an RDD of Key/Value (key being the column index) is it possible to load it into a dataframe?
For example:

```
(0,1), (0,1), (0,2), (1,2), (1,10), (1,20), (3,18), (3,18), (3,18)
```

And have the dataframe look like:

```
1,2,18
1,10,18
2,20,18
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes it's possible (tested with Spark 1.3.1) :

```
>>> rdd = sc.parallelize([(0,1), (0,1), (0,2), (1,2), (1,10), (1,20), (3,18), (3,18), (3,18)])
>>> sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, ["id", "score"])
Out[2]: DataFrame[id: bigint, score: bigint]
```

Comment: Is this equivolent to `rdd.toDF( ["id", "score"])`?

Comment: 'RDD' object has no attribute 'toDF' . Facing this error

Comment: I am using 1.6 spark and pyspark. Unable to load the sql.SQLContext and create DataFrame out of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([(0,1), (0,1), (0,2), (1,2), (1,10), (1,20), (3,18), (3,18), (3,18)])

df=rdd.toDF(['id','score'])

df.show()
```

answer is:

```
+---+-----+
| id|score|
+---+-----+
|  0|    1|
|  0|    1|
|  0|    2|
|  1|    2|
|  1|   10|
|  1|   20|
|  3|   18|
|  3|   18|
|  3|   18|
+---+-----+
```